# Two activities in task manager of same app

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

My application have two activities, say `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`. Main activity is declared as `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` and its orientation is always `portrait`. Second activity is always has `landscape` orientation.

In some devices, everything is alright and in task manager there is only one instance of my app, but in some devices (like Samsung S7), when I launch `SecondActivity`, there will be two instances of my app in task manager like this image:

[image]

My guess is that something is wrong with the `launchMode` of the `MainActivty` but I need it to be `singleInstance`. Any suggestion?

**EDIT:**

MainActivity in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and second:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activities.SecondActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

launching code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),  
intent.putExtra("VideoUri", filmGet.getOutput().getData().getFilmTrailer());
startActivity(intent);
```

If it helps, I launch `SecondActivity` from a fragment.

Comment: try changing the launch mode to singleTop or singleTask.

Comment: how are you launching your new activity? Can you share `manifest.xml` and  `launching intent`?

Comment: I need to relaunch MainActivity from another activity so singleTop is not what I want. Also I read somewhere that for a singleTask activity, every time you launch the app, singleTask activity will come to the front and I don't want this.

Comment: I guess, you need to set `android:taskAffinity="com.whatever"` on your both activities explicitly. Set same affinity for both and check if it works.

Comment: @mallaudin, thanks for your suggestion, but I tested your way and unfortunately it didn't worked.

Comment: @shadoWalker If you want only one instance of your app in recent app section then why don't you try `singleTop`.

Comment: See the third comment of this section. Think activities like this: A -> B -> C and now I want to relaunch A and remove it from backstack. Then singleTop is not what I want. singleTop only differs with normal activities when the activity is already on top and it will not relaunch. But if activities were like A -> B -> C and you relaunch A, then backstack will be: A -> B -> C -> A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after reading @sharan comment and some googling, it made me to read some google documents. According to docs, there isn't any difference between `android:launchMode=singleInstance` and `android:launchMode=singleTask` but one. They both make your activity `singleton` and so you will never have two instances of it. The only difference between them is that `singleInstance` will prevent the task from attaching any other activity while `singleTask` has not this limitation. Any other things about them are the same.

So, for anyone who is reading this post, I'll recommend you to never use `singleInstance` launch mode unless you exactly need what it has. Because if you have only one activity in your app, then there will be no differences between `singleInstance` and `singleTask`. And if you have more than one activity, then I'll recommend you to all of your activities belong to one task.

In short, change `singleInstance` to `singleTask` and you are go.

Comment: To add to the above, singleInstance is favourable towards single activity application(which is the current go to method). Application which has multiple activities should use singleTask. Correct me if im wrong.